# Why is putchar printing formatted output?

Tags: c, string, escaping, string-formatting

I've wanted to learn more about the C standard library, so I decided to implement `printf` using only the `putchar` function. I'd barely started when something odd happened. All I'd done was write a loop to print a verbatim copy of the format string, and then I realized that all the escape sequences, (`\n`, `\t`, etc.) had already been parsed and "properly" output.

Here's the minimal code:

```
int my_printf(const char* s){
    size_t i;
    char c;
    for (i = 0; (c = *(s + i)) != '\0'; ++i){
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    my_printf("Here\t1\n0\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a literal `Here\t1\n0\n` to be output, but I instead got:

```
Here    1
0
```

Any idea why this happening? My first thought was that the compiler I'm using, (gcc), was trying to help by pre-analyzing the format string, but that seems odd, since it would cause a *lot* of problems, since it would break any `char` array. So, does anyone know why this is happening? And is this behavior defined in the standard? Thank you for any help!

Edit: As mafso stated in their answer, the replacements are done at compile time, and it *is* standard. Section 5.1.1.2.1.5 of the standard has the actual text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape sequences are replaced at compile time, not at runtime by `printf`. `"\n"` is a string starting with a *literal* new-line character (it’s the only way to put a literal new-line character into a string).

The only part of the string `printf` interprets are conversion specification, which always start with a `%` sign, (and the 0-terminator, of course), every other character is printed literally. You don’t need to do anything further.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it is done at compile time. I'll cite the standard in an update to my question, since I found the actual text. Thank you!